# Bind Checkbox inside ListBox to List<String>

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have ListBox with an ItemTemplate with a Checkbox inside.
Now I want to bind my List, so that each Checkbox gets its content from the array.
Sounds easy but it doesn't work.

This is what I have:

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" x:Name="ListAvailableHours" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="0,9.5,0,0" Height="Auto">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <CheckBox Content="{Binding}" />
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And my code behind

```
List<string> AvailableHours = new List<string>();
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
AvailableHours.Add(now.ToString());
AvailableHours.Add(now.AddHours(1).ToString());
AvailableHours.Add(now.AddHours(2).ToString());
AvailableHours.Add(now.AddHours(3).ToString());
AvailableHours.Add(now.AddHours(4).ToString());

ListAvailableHours.ItemsSource = AvailableHours;
```

When i try and open this page I get the following exception:

```
"An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occured     in WindowsPhone.exe but was not handled in user code.

WinRT Information: E_UNKOWN_ERROR [Line:44 Position:44]

Additional Information: The text associated with this error code could not be found."
```

Line 44, Pos 44 points to the end of

```
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

so I assume something with the Binding is off?

Comment: Is there a DataContext set to ListBox? try setting ListAvailableHours.DataContext = this before setting the ItemsSource

Comment: There is no binding at the time the exception is thrown. Try setting the ListView.ItemSource property to something in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

I feewl so stupid.
I had some items hardcoded before, and have set SelectedIndex=0 so it was selected. Now that I added a DataTemplate, this obviously was wrong :)

Removed the SelectedIndex, now it works, thanks.